# Extract multiple object values from JSON file and save to .txt file?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file with 20 objects, each containing a `resource` parameter with an associated value. I would like to extract the value of `resource` for each object, and save that value as a line in a txt file.

The structure of the JSON is:

```json
"objects": [
{"created": "2020-10-04", "name": "john", "resource": "api/john/",}
{"created": "2020-10-04", "name": "paul", "resource": "api/paul/",}
{"created": "2020-10-04", "name": "george", "resource": "api/george/",}
{"created": "2020-10-04", "name": "ringo", "resource": "api/ringo/",}
]
```

So far, I have got the following code, however this can only get the `resource` value from the first object, and does not let me write it to a txt file using Python.

```
with open(input_json) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
resource = (data["objects"][1]["resource"])

values = resource.items()
k = {str(key): str(value) for key, value in values}
with open ('resource-list.txt', 'w') as resource_file:
    resource_file.write(k)
```

Comment: When I run the program, parsing the JSON leads to an error. Please provide a [mcve]. _So far, I have got the following code, however this can only get the resource value from the first object, and does not let me write it to a txt file using Python._ Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You have to use lists:

```
txtout="" 
with open(input_json) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    objects = data["objects"]
    for jobj in objects:
        txtout = txtout + jobj["resource"] + "\n"

with open ('resource-list.txt', 'w') as resource_file:
    resource_file.write(txtout)
```

Comment: Thank you obayhan!

Answer (score 0):

hi there new Pythonista!
well the thing you missed here is the part where you `iterate` over your json object.

```
with open(input_json) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
resource = (data["objects"][1]["resource"])  # right here you simply took the second object (which is the [1] position)
```

a decet fix would be:

```
with open(input_json) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

all_items = []  # lets keep here all resource values
for item in data["objects"]:  # iterate over entire items
    all_items.append(item["resource"])  # push the necessary info

# lets concat every item to one string since it's only made of 20, it will not make our buffer explode
to_write = "\n".join(all_items)
with open("resource-list.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(to_write)
```

and we’re done!

Comment: Thank you Hagai!